# Block executing specific .exe files based on their md5 hash

Tags: c++, windows, security, process, driver

I want to write a simple program that blocks executing certain .exe files based on t their md5 hash value (like notepad.exe ...).

I searched for this problem and I found that I need to register a callback this method is the start [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953(v=vs.85).aspx) and here is a sample callback:

```
VOID PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB(HANDLE ParentProcessId, HANDLE ProcessId, PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo)
{  

    if (CreateInfo) // if the info is available
    {   
        DbgPrint("Created Process info \r\n");
        DbgPrint("\tIs Sub-System Process: %wZ\r\n", CreateInfo->IsSubsystemProcess);
        if (!CreateInfo->IsSubsystemProcess) {
            DbgPrint("\tParent ProcessId: %d", CreateInfo->ParentProcessId);
            DbgPrint("\tFile name: %wZ \r\n", CreateInfo->FileObject->FileName);
            DbgPrint("\tImageFileName: %wZ \r\n", CreateInfo->ImageFileName);
            DbgPrint("\tCommandLine: %wZ \r\n", CreateInfo->CommandLine);
            DbgPrint("\tCreationStatus: %x \r\n", CreateInfo->CreationStatus);

            CreateInfo->CreationStatus = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I set the `CreationStatus` to `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` which blocks execution of every process :), How can I conditionally block execution of certain processes? What if a have list of unallowed .exe files inside a SqLite database? How can I connect this callback with some service which tells which file should be run and which shouldn't?

I also have seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559917(v=vs.85).aspx#best) recommendation by Microsoft which says:

- Keep notify routines short and simple.
- Do not make calls into a user mode service to validate the process, thread, or image.
- Do not make registry calls.
- Do not make blocking and/or Interprocess Communication (IPC) function calls.
- Do not synchronize with other threads because it can lead to reentrancy deadlocks.

It kind of warns and limit us in this callback, so my question is how can I achieve my goal? (limiting execution of some .exe files based on their hash value stored in a SqlLite database?)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your signature for `PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB` is incorrect - first parameter must be `PEPROCESS Process` (pointer to ne process object) but not `HANDLE ParentProcessId`. you copy-paste this from msdn page, but error here.

about solution - because `PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB` executed in critical region with [*normal kernel APCs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/types-of-apcs) disabled - we very restricted todo something here. but we can queue [*normal kernel APC*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/types-of-apcs) to current thread. it will be executed just we leave critical region. and here, in Normal routine we already can free read data from file, wait, query user mode. for terminate process we can simply call [`ZwTerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567115(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
void* __cdecl operator new(size_t size, POOL_TYPE PoolType)
{
    return ExAllocatePool(PoolType, size);
}

void __cdecl operator delete(PVOID pv)
{
    ExFreePool(pv);
}

// asm routines: call corresponding *Routine and jmp ObfDereferenceObject for g_DriverObject
VOID CALLBACK RundownRoutine(PKAPC );
VOID CALLBACK KernelRoutine(PKAPC , PKNORMAL_ROUTINE *, PVOID * , PVOID * ,PVOID * );
VOID CALLBACK NormalRoutine(PVOID , PVOID ,PVOID );

VOID CALLBACK _NormalRoutine (
                      PVOID ,
                      PEPROCESS Process,
                      PFILE_OBJECT FileObject
                      )
{
    __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))

    DbgPrint("NormalRoutine(%p, %p %s)\n", Process, FileObject, PsGetProcessImageFileName(Process));

    if (NeedTerminate(Process, FileObject))
    {
        HANDLE hProcess;
        if (0 <= ObOpenObjectByPointer(Process, 0, 0, PROCESS_TERMINATE, *PsProcessType, KernelMode, &hProcess))
        {
            status = ZwTerminateProcess(hProcess, STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED);
            ZwClose(hProcess);
        }
    }

    ObfDereferenceObject(FileObject);
    ObfDereferenceObject(Process);
}

VOID CALLBACK _RundownRoutine(PKAPC Apc);
{
    __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))

    DbgPrint("--Apc<%p>\n", Apc);
    delete Apc;
}

VOID CALLBACK _KernelRoutine(
                             PKAPC Apc, 
                             PKNORMAL_ROUTINE * /*NormalRoutine*/, 
                             PVOID * /*NormalContext*/, 
                             PVOID * /*SystemArgument1*/, 
                             PVOID * /*SystemArgument2*/
                             )
{
    __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))

    DbgPrint("KernelRoutine<%p>\n", Apc);

    ObfReferenceObject(g_DriverObject);//NormalRoutine will be called

    _RundownRoutine(Apc);
}

void CreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(PEPROCESS Process, HANDLE ProcessId, PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo)
{
  PFILE_OBJECT FileObject;

    if (CreateInfo && !CreateInfo->IsSubsystemProcess && (PFILE_OBJECT FileObject = CreateInfo->FileObject))
    {
        // for do main job out of critical region
        if (PKAPC Apc = new(NonPagedPool) KAPC)
        {
            KeInitializeApc(Apc, KeGetCurrentThread(), OriginalApcEnvironment, KernelRoutine, RundownRoutine, NormalRoutine, KernelMode, 0);

            DbgPrint("++Apc<%p> \n", Apc);

            ObfReferenceObject(g_DriverObject);
            ObfReferenceObject(Process);
            ObfReferenceObject(FileObject);

            if (!KeInsertQueueApc(Apc, Process, FileObject, IO_NO_INCREMENT))
            {
                ObfDereferenceObject(FileObject);
                ObfDereferenceObject(Process);
                ObfDereferenceObject(g_DriverObject);
                delete Apc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, How can I do it in reverse though? I mean block it first and re execute the program if it is allowed? which one is better you think?

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii - i not understand what you mean under *I mean block it first and re execute the program if it is allowed* - we can only or terminate new process or let it run as is. in NormalRoutine we already can read file (we have fileobject), can calc md5 direct in kernel. can and ask user mode, however of course better if possible, do all tasks in kernel

Comment: my bad :), I am very new to kernel and low level stuff :), by the way I didn't understand your last sentence, doing all the tasks in kernel, what do you mean by all? reading file, calculating md5, validating if the file is allowed/not allowed.

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii need try to all what possible in kernel, without ask user mode. read file we easy can. calc md5 too. what already do with md5, this already question.

Comment: aha ! you mean do as much as you can in kernel, correct me if I am wrong, how do application control/anti exe programs works then ? any thoughts on that? I mean they should at least at some point ask some service to decide what to do with the current process?

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii - yes, i mean exactly do as much as you can in kernel. how ask, if need, user mode already another, wide question. this is very depended on task. however in NormalRoutine you already can call to user mode

Comment: say minifilter drivers usually use `FltCreateCommunicationPort` and `FltSendMessage`. any driver can use LPC ports. but this undocumented (`ZwConnectPort`, `LpcRequestWaitReplyPort`, `LpcRequestPort` in kernel, port created via `ZwCreatePort` in user mode). can be used named pipes. can shared memory and events. etc

Comment: thanks for your valuable information, I will ask other questions in case of necessity.